# why vector begin() pointing to second element of vector and while displaying a all element vector after few pusback() abort the program?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stl

I am was just writing the small vector program in visual stdudio 2010.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>

    void main() {
        using namespace std;
        vector<int> myvector;

        myvector.push_back(1);
        myvector.push_back(2);
        myvector.push_back(3);
        myvector.push_back(4);

        for( auto i = myvector.begin(); i != myvector.end(); ++i)
        {
            cout << myvector[*i] <<endl;
        }
    }
```

expected output should be

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

but I am getting this error:

[image]

I checked over web everywhere I have seen same sample program to use vector.
Note: in my program myvector is pointing to the second element of vector. I don't know why it is not pointing to the first element

.

Comment: `myvector[4]` is out of bounds. The valid range of indices is `[0, 3]`

Comment: but i am checking i != myvector.end();

Comment: `myvector` isn't pointing to anything. It's a vector, not a pointer. `i` starts off "pointing" to the first element. You then use each element's value to index the vector. Note that debugging this with a debugger would show you that `i` "points" to the `4` when the assertion is fired.

Comment: @Suri: did you mean `cout << *i <<endl;` ?

Comment: @chris so myvetor.begin() should point to first element i.e. 1 not 2 but in my pgramm it is pointing to 2.

Comment: @Suri, No, and you can easily test it by printing `*myvector.begin()`, which will print 1. Since indices are zero-based, using that 1 to index the vector will of course give back 2.

Comment: ya got the point cout << *i should get the value not myvector[*i]. I done, stupid question. rightly downvoted my questions.

Comment: @Suri `expected output should be 1 2 3 4 5`  How can that be when your code only inserted `1 2 3 4` into the vector?  Where would the `5` come from?

Comment: I can't believe no one commented on the `void main()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This out you will get desired output It worked fine with g++4.2:

```
  #include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    vector<int> myvector;


    myvector.push_back(1);
    myvector.push_back(2);
    myvector.push_back(3);
    myvector.push_back(4);

    for( vector<int>::iterator i = myvector.begin(); i < myvector.end(); ++i)
    {

        cout<<*i<<endl;

    }
    //even check this second loop
    for(int i=0;i<myvector.size();i++)
    {
        cout<<myvector.at(i)<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You added four elements to the vector. So the valid range of indices for the subscript operator of class `std::vector` is `0 - 3`

Let's consider the following statement

```
cout << myvector[*i] <<endl;
```

For the first iterator that is for the iterator that is equal to `myvector.begin()` the value of `*i` is equal to 1. For the last dereferenced iterator that is for the iterator that is equal to   `myvector.end() - 1` the value of `*i` is equal to 4.
As you are using these values as the indices of the subscript operator when the used range of indices is `1 - 4` This range does not coincide with the valid range of indices that is equal to `0 - 3`. For example the vector has no element with the index equal to 4. And the compiler reports about this erroneous situation saying that `vector subscript out of range`

You could write simply as

```
cout << *i <<endl;
```

In this case you would get the predicted and correct result.:)

Or you could write

```
cout << myvector[*i - 1] <<endl;
```

In this case you would get the same correct result.

```
1 2 3 4
```

The indices of vectors as of arrays are always start with 0.

Take into account that if your compiler supports features of the C++ 2011 Standard then instead of these statements

```
    vector<int> myvector;

    myvector.push_back(1);
    myvector.push_back(2);
    myvector.push_back(3);
    myvector.push_back(4);
```

you could write simply

```
    vector<int> myvector = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

that uses the initialization-list constructor.